# different domains disabled in polylang

Tags: multi-language, domain, domain-mapping, plugin-polylang

**Short:** In `Languages -> Settings -> URL modifications`, the options "The language is set from the subdomain name in pretty permalinks" and "The language is set from different domains" are disabled. Why is this and how can I make these boxes selectable? I am particularly interested in the last option (different domains).

Versions: Wordpress 5.5.1, Polylang 2.8.3

**Background:** My goal is a bilingual website (single web site install using polylang). I have two domains domain.aa and domain.bb for the languages AA and BB, respectively. Both are pointing on my document root and the .htaccess is pointing to the wordpress directory:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?domain.aa$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/wordpress/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /wordpress/$1
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?domain.aa$
RewriteRule ^(/)?$ wordpress/index.php [L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?domain.bb$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/wordpress/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /wordpress/$1
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?domain.bb$
RewriteRule ^(/)?$ wordpress/index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Then, I installed Polylang and there's my problem.

Comment: I'd guess those options are from Polylang, not WordPress itself, so you might do better asking them directly.

Answer (score 0):

You must change the Wordpress permalink settings.

Go to Settings>Permalink
and chose "post name" and save then reload the Polylang settings and the options should be available.

I have not tried it with other permalink settings, but it cannot be "plain" which is the default.

It took me 2 hours to figure this out...